# How to find the number of NULL/NOT NULL values from each column in a table in SQL Server [C#]?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have the following code to get all the columns from a SQL table in C#:

```
public List<string> GetColumns(string tableName)
    {
        var columns = new List<string>();
        
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_sqlServerConnectionString.SqlServerConnectionString))
        {
            
            conn.Open();
            var selectQuery = $"SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '{tableName}'";
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, conn))
            {                            
                using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
                {
                    columns.Add(reader["COLUMN_NAME"].ToString());
                }
            }
            conn.Close();
        }           

        return columns;
    }
```

***In C#***, how do I find out the number of NULL, NOT NULL and TOTAL values from each of these columns?

For example:

```
COLUMN 1, COLUMN 2


X, A
Y, NULLL
Y, NULL
Z, B
NULL, C
NULL, NULL
```

So for COLUMN1

```
TOTAL # of values: 6
NULL: 2
NOT NULL: 4
```

So for COLUMN2

```
TOTAL # of values: 6
NULL: 3
NOT NULL: 3
```

Total should be same for all columns.

Comment: Why no parameterized query for the table name? This is not SQL injection safe, and it would be so easy to fix it.

Comment: Do you want to count the number of NULL values in a specific table row? Or the number of nullable columns from the table definition?

Comment: I updated the question to make it more clear. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`NULL` values are excluded from all aggregate functions except for `count()`, so
. . .
To determine the number of null/non-null values in a column,

```
select sum( case when t.col_1 is null then 1 else 0 end ) as null_count,
       sum( case when t.col_1 is null then 0 else 1 end ) as not_null_count,
       count(*)                                           as total
from someTable t
```

Comment: `count(*) - count(t.col_1), count(t.col_1), count(*)`?

Comment: @GSerg — I believe my version more clearly and succinctly states what it's trying to do. Yours requires that the reader know and understand how aggregate functions and null values behave. And one writes code for human beings to read, not for computers to read.

Comment: Isn't the reader required to "know and understand how aggregate functions and null values behave" in order to understand why `sum` is used where `count` would seemingly suffice? The difference between `count(name)` and `count(*)` is the basic information about `count` that the user must understand. The construct with `sum`, on the other hand, is asking for a explanatory comment.